# BigQuery filtering selftext that contains a word in all possible posts in a subreddit

Tags: google-bigquery, reddit

I'm trying to get posts and their comments in the AskDocs subreddit about Asperger, this sql works fine to get the posts

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc), MONTH, 'America/New_York') AS date_agg, title,selftext

FROM
  `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.*`
WHERE
  (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "2016_01" AND "2019_03" OR _TABLE_SUFFIX = 'full_corpus_201512')
  AND subreddit = 'AskDocs'
  AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(selftext, r'Asperger')

ORDER BY
  date_agg
```

But I'm not sure if with this I get all the posts that are available, I got 169 rows but I'm trying to get as much as possible in AskDocs about this subject.

And the second question is because I'm trying to link each post with its comments, I found this here in SO

```
#standardSQL
SELECT posts.title, comments.body
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2016_01` AS comments
JOIN `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2016_01`  AS posts
ON posts.id = SUBSTR(comments.link_id, 4) 
WHERE posts.id = '43go1r'
```

But when I try to merge my code in here I have a real mess

Answer (score 0):

For the first query, you are obtaining 169 rows since you are using a capital A within the regex and selftext that contains the word Asperger will be listed only, e.g.: *Asperger*, *Asperger's*, *Aspergers*, etc. However, the titles with the words *asperger*, *asperger's*, *aspergers*, will not be listed since you are using a capital A within the regex only. To list the words that includes  the lowercase, you need to use **[aA]** within the regex, which will display 241 rows:

```
AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(posts.selftext, r'[aA]sperger')
```

For join the tables, you can use the following query:

```
WITH
  comments AS (
  SELECT
    link_id,
    body
  FROM
    `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.201*`
  WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "6_01"
    AND "9_03"
    AND subreddit = 'AskDocs' ),
  posts AS (
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc), MONTH, 'America/New_York') AS date_agg,
    id,
    selftext,
    title
  FROM
    `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.*`
  WHERE
    (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "2016_01"
      AND "2019_03"
      OR _TABLE_SUFFIX = 'full_corpus_201512')
    AND subreddit = 'AskDocs'
    AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(selftext, r'[aA]sperger') )
SELECT
  posts.date_agg AS Date,
  posts.title AS Post,
  posts.selftext AS Text,
  comments.body AS Comment
FROM
  comments
JOIN
  posts
ON
  posts.id = SUBSTR(comments.link_id, 4)
ORDER BY
  Date,
  Post
```

Note: I used different wildcards since tables are not the same on both datasets to [filter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute#prune_partitioned_queries) partitions and optimize query computation.